# A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried internet search on this issue and it is very common with many suggestions. The problem started with an update to VS2019 in which I paused because my projects in VSCode were breaking.I did a system restore and when I tried to start VSCode I got a message saying my installation was corrupt. So I reinstalled to the latest version and now get this error.

A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found...

I found 3 extensions that needed updating so I do so but did not fix this problem. Do not know if I need to update the .Net Core since it looks like a version mismatch. It seems these updates are wreckless since they always cause thing to go wrong.s

Comment: error message continued:

Comment: Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\dotnet.runtimeconfig.json file specifying the appropriate framework

this file not found.

Comment: where is this file, dotnet.runtimeconfig.json?

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this problem, it means you are using Windows.

This official microsoft live share github page explains how to fix the issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/102

Especially, check out this comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/102#issuecomment-366509735

- make vscode is up to date
- uninstall live share from vscode
- close vscode completely
- restart vscode as administrator
- reinstall live share

I should add:

- close completely vscode and restart it